# Halcon - Select subregion with highest Y value

Tags: area, region, halcon

I have a region that contains multiple smaller regions. After using `connection` and `select_shape` to clean it up i am left with one single region. It happens sometimes tough that 2 or 3 regions meet the criteria and are displayed.

I need a way to select the region that is positioned lowest in the picture. So with the highest Y value. The only way that comes to my mind is use the 'area_center' comand and then iterate through all found regions, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function smallest_rectangle1(Regions, Row1, Column1, Row2, Column2).

In this case, the tuple Row2 contains the higher Y values of every region.